# Scraping and parsing the <script> tag using BS4 (or is there something better)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a list of breweries with their latitude and longitude from the website https://www.brewbound.com/breweries. This is what the portion of the source code I'm interested in from the website looks like:

```
    <script>
var locations = [['Wolf Pack Brewing Company', 44.6620529, -111.0994608, '/breweries/Wolf_Pack_Brewing_Co'],['Defiant Brewing Company', 41.0584046, -74.022847, '/breweries/Defiant_Brewing_Co'],
```

with a continued list of breweries. Each brewery is listed in between `[]` with the name, lat, long, and website. What I want to do is scrape the `var locations` and create a DataFrame from it with each brewery as a row and the columns containing the information listed.

I've been able to scrape everything from the website with the `<script>` tag (which includes multiple sections of the page). I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
    url = "https://www.brewbound.com/breweries"
    r = requests.get(url)
    html_contents = r.text
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'html.parser')
    script = html_soup.find_all('script')
```

This is the code I wrote to get all `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` won't help you with content of `<script>` tags. But you could however use `re` and `ast.literal_eval` to extract the information:

```
import re
import requests
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://www.brewbound.com/breweries"
r = requests.get(url)

l = literal_eval(re.search(r'var locations = (\[.*?\]);', r.text, flags=re.DOTALL)[1])
pprint(l)
```

Prints:

```
[['Wolf Pack Brewing Company',
  44.6620529,
  -111.0994608,
  '/breweries/Wolf_Pack_Brewing_Co'],
 ['Defiant Brewing Company',
  41.0584046,
  -74.022847,
  '/breweries/Defiant_Brewing_Co'],
 ['El Toro Brewing Company',
  37.1465525,
  -121.6219873,
  '/breweries/El_Toro_Brewing_Co'],
 ['Sebago Brewing Company',
  43.679212,
  -70.396424,
  '/breweries/Sebago_Brewing_Co'],

...etc.
```